# How to set fields in an abstract class?

Tags: java, abstract, access-modifiers

I have an abstract class with a field in it, which should have following properties:

- readonly for the public interface
- writeonly for the subclasses

My question now is: how should I set and initialize this field?

```
public abstract class A {
    // initialize it here ?
    private int field = 0;

    // initialize it in constructor ?
    protected A(int field)
    {
        this.field = field;
    }
      
    // use protected setter ?
    protected void setField(int val){
        this.field = val;
    }

    // or use protected field
    protected int field;

    public int getField(){
        return field;
    }
}
```

How to initialize/access this field?

```
public class B extends A {
    
    public B(int val){
        super(val);
        // or
        setField(val);
        // or
        field = val;
    }
}
```

and is it a good idea to use something like a protected constructor?

Comment: why do I need static variables ?

Comment: @KevinEsche I think he means about static data, not static variable

Comment: @jam because the title says so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically on your need

If you want to initialize super class field at the creation of child object it self, then you could call `super(val);`

If you want to create your child object independent of parent object's field values. use Default contructor for child class and if required to set parent value call `setField(val);` method on child object.

> is it a good idea to use smth. like a protected constructor ?

Yes if you really want to restrict access for the classes within the package

Comment: so protected constructors for abstract classes, are used that way
I thougth this could be a design lack

Comment: and what about using a protected field instead of the setter ?

Comment: @jam It is not good idea to expose your fields directly even for the sub classes, it is always safe to provide access via Setters and Getters. So IMO protected field is not a good idea.

Comment: okay so use setter. further I am confused about using a constructor for abstract classes since they are not allowed to be instantiated

Comment: @jam Don't be confused about it. if you want to initialize static data at the time of object creation it self it is a good idea to have constructor.  Instead of setting values to number of fields you could constructor to avoid that.  consider a use case you are developing an API (Paid), developers who need to use your api must supply api key. Developes may forgot to set api if they use setters. At this situtation it is good idea to force them to supply api key via constructor itself.

Comment: @jam And also consider constructor as just method. it is `new` that will create object. so don't worry